# Oracle SQL date comparison

Tags: sql, oracle, date

why if date1 is of type date with value: 31-DIC-99 00:00:00

this instruction is true

```
to_char(date1) = to_char(TO_DATE('9999-12-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

and this is false?

```
date1 = TO_DATE('9999-12-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Thanks

Comment: In addition to the previous comments addressing your immediate question, it should also be pointed out that you should always, _always_ use 4-digit years.  I don't care what you may have heard, the Y2K bug was very real.  I was part of the legion of developers who busted their butts for 2 years, converting all of our code to use 4-digit years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dates in Oracle have time components -- even if you don't seem them when the values are printed out.  When you convert the value to a string with no format specified, then the time component is set to zero.

I would recommend writing the logic as:

```
 trunc(date1) = date '9999-12-31'
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
date1 >= date '9999-12-31'
```

You are referring to the maximum date value, so there are no dates with larger values . . . but there are larger values on the same date with a time.

I do not recommend converting dates to string, except for output purposes (or if needed for a very specific reason).  Date/time functions are usually quite sufficient for operations on date/time values.

Answer (score 1):

Here, Your first condition is true because you are using the `TO_CHAR` both sides and it will convert both of the dates into the same string. (string comparision)

```
to_char(date1) = to_char(TO_DATE('9999-12-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

Let's say `NLS_DATE_FORAMT` is `dd.mon.rrrr` then your comparison will be

```
to_char(date1,'dd.mon.rrrr') = to_char(TO_DATE('9999-12-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'dd.mon.rrrr')
```

The second condition is not true as both the sides are different - date1 may have time portion and right side expression do not have it.

```
date1 = TO_DATE('9999-12-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

date1 contains time part so one date will be the same as the second date if they are the same until seconds precision.

You can use trunc to remove the time portion from date1:

```
trunc(date1) = TO_DATE('9999-12-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```